# Put javascript variable value in src of audio

Tags: html5-audio

Was using **embed** to play Flash SWF files to play random background music with no controls.  Since `Flash` is going away, I want to replace it using `<audio>` tag with controls.  Have a folder named *music* containing multiple MP3 files with simple names (*Song1.mp3*,*song2.mp3*,etc.). I have a script that generates a random number for variable `Whichsong`

```
(WhichSong="Music/song"+(Math.floor(Math.random()*23))+".swf"
```

That varible is used as the path to the song to play

```
(document.write('<embed src="'+WhichSong+'" quality="high" width="0" height="0")
```

I have seen the code here that suggests that I can use a similar method to put URL information in the `<Audio SRC="'+WhichSong+'" >` tag. However, nothing I have tried has worked. I've tried with/without quotes, with/without **+**, with/without **'**, and various combination of all.  Nothing works. No sound, no controls.

Sample code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>

<div align="center" id="soundtrack"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var WhichSong="Music/song"+(Math.floor(Math.random()*23))+".mp3"

document.getElementById('soundtrack').innerHTML="<audio controls id='background_audio1'><source src='music/5.mp3'>Your browser does not support the audio element.</audio>";

</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How does it not work? I would suggest using something like jsbin.com and `createElement('audio')` then `setAttribute('src', yourSource)` but it might not be able to load cross-site audio. You should be able to see that the source is set correctly by inspecting the element. Also, `<script>` is javascript by default

Comment: Do you get a 404?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WhichSong` variable isn't going to be interpreted within your innerHTML string if the whole thing is quoted. You'd need to either break out of the quotes:

`"<source src=\"" + WhichSong + "\"></source>"`, or use a [template string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) as in the example below. Other than that it seems to be fine.

```js
function setSong () {
  const WhichSong="Music/song"+(Math.floor(Math.random()*23))+".mp3"
  document.getElementById('soundtrack').innerHTML=`
    <audio controls
      id='background_audio1'>
        <source src='${WhichSong}' />
        Your browser does not support the audio element.
    </audio>
    <div>${WhichSong}</div>
  `;
}
```

```html
<div id="soundtrack"></div>
<button onClick="setSong()">Set Song</button>
```

Comment: Ray Hatfield, I'm a big fan of the KISS policy. Your simple change to break out the "s worked perfectly in my case.  Just a simple formatting change..  Now I'm going to chase a solution to add a event listen for end and load another song- an continue to play.  Might even try to add a button to select another song..   Sometimes I set my goals way to high.  LOL